# Thunderbird: How to edit server connection settings of already existing accounts?

Tags: thunderbird, ssl, imap, smtp, tls

How can I change the server connection settings for already existing accounts from previous `STARTTLS` to desired `SSL/TLS`?

---

Of course, even for existing accounts in menue `Account Settings` -> `Server Settings` I can change `IMAP/POP3` to `SSL/TLS`. However, this change does only affect `POP3/IMAP` while `SMTP` will keep the old `STARTTLS`-configuration. Therefore I also want to change `SMTP`-settings to `SSL/TLS`, but there is no graphical input option available for it.

How can I edit this? Maybe in `about:config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's in a non-intuitive place.  From the menu:

```
Edit | Account Settings
```

On the left panel, you'll see your different accounts.  The SMTP settings are not merged with each account.  Rather, there is a link for them at the very end of the accounts list.  If you have a number of accounts, you would never know it was there, out of sight.

Scroll all the way to the bottom of the accounts list, past **Local Folders**, to **Outgoing Server (SMTP)**

Click that and the accounts will show on the right side.  Click the account you want to change, then click the Edit button.